# Lua: Perfectly Truncate a Value

Tags: string, math, lua, truncate, floor

This script displays a value in a program:

```
string.format("%d", math.floor(self:value())) -- Where self:value() is a number like 4.1256913947
```

This script takes that same value and prints it to my console.

```
math.floor(value) -- Where value is the same number as self:value() was...it's just being sent to another function as well
```

The problem is the display value and the console printed value don't match up. This happens rarely and infrequently, but when a user enters data that goes over the integer slightly (ie 4.0029893417) or whatever then it will floor it to 3 in this case for no reason. I have tried math.ceil but the reverse effect happens when it's to close (ie 4.89898989) it prints 5 but displays 4. Is there a way to make it so the number perfectly truncates? Thus displaying correctly and printing correctly?

Note: The Value is unchangeable, as sometimes those extra decimals need to be there and are dealt with accordingly in other places/functions.

Thanks :)

Comment: The problem is probaly somewhere else. Provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of curiosity, I've performed some tests, using some of the conditions you described. Unfortunately (or fortunately) I wasn't able to reproduce the problem you're talking about.
The snippet below adds and subtracts random numbers, so that the result is around 4 and then compares both methods of printing (compares by produced string):

```
for i=1,10000000 do
    local value = 3.9 + math.random() * 0.2
    local s1 = string.format("%d", math.floor(value))
    local s2 = tostring(math.floor(value))
    if s1 ~= s2 then print "Error" end
end
```

As you can guess, 'Error' doesn't show up.

I've made yet another experiment:

```
local l = 4
for i=1,100000 do
    local k = math.pow(10,-i)
    local rand = math.random() * 0.1
    local subtracted = l - k - rand
    if math.floor(subtracted + k + rand) < 4 then
        print "error"
    end
end
```

By adding very small number I was hoping to get similar result to what you describe, but again, problem doesn't show up.

So I must conclude that the problem probably lays in the difference between function self:value() and variable value (they indeed have different values sometimes).

Comment: As someone else pointed out as well, it was another section causing the problem. Apparently the person before me forget to tell me there is another script or portion that overrides the same value in the display, so the display is "inaccurate" to a degree. The function was being called with the original function in mind (ie, string.format(%d math.floored etc) and this line (which messed with the values)... `string.format("%." .. math.abs(math.ceil(-math.log(self._step) / math.log(10))) .. "f", self:value())`  which as you can see will make the value displayed be slightly off (at least, I think)

Comment: So I added a check on the self._step for being either a whole number (of which there is only value ever for that, 1 OR for being anything else...use the longer version of the string. So far it works, but if anyone is willing to try it to verify or see if that is indeed the problem, that would be appreciated. I am not that great with logs and not with how Lua handles them.